# Spring Injection Error with Class that implements interface and @Cacheable

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am having some problems with spring injection when I added the @Cacheable annotation to the CustomerLookupInvoker class.:

```
public class CustomerLookupInvoker extends
RsiInvoker<CustomerLookupServiceRQ, CustomerLookupServiceRS> {
```

and the RsiInvoker is an abstract class that implements Invoker like this:

```
public abstract class RsiInvoker<T_Input extends Input, T_Output extends
Output> implements Invoker<T_Input, T_Output> {
```

And the invoker class is this:

```
 public interface Invoker<T_Input extends Input, T_Output extends Output> {
     T_Output process(T_Input input);
 }
```

My spring injection looks like:

```
  <bean id="Invoker" class="com.xxx.pricing.sao.Invoker">
  </bean>

  <bean id="CustomerLookupInvoker" parent="Invoker" class="com.xxxx.pricing.sao.CustomerLookupInvoker">
    <property name="customerLookupAdapter" ref="CustomerLookupAdapter"/>
    <property name="responseMessageAdapter" ref="ResponseMessageAdapter"/>
  </bean>            

  <bean id="CustomerLookupAdapter" class="com.xxxx.pricing.domain.adapter.CustomerLookupAdapter">
    <property name="mapper" ref="Mapper"/>  
  </bean>

  <bean id="HcPricingSystemPivotCommon" class="com.xxxx.pricing.pivot.HcPricingSystemPivotCommon">
    <property name="messageHandlerUtil" ref="MessageHandlerUtil"/>
    <property name="ecarsApplicationPropertyUtil" ref="EcarsApplicationPropertyUtil"/>
    <property name="customerLookupInvoker" ref="CustomerLookupInvoker"/>
  </bean>
```

We are using ehcache and I added @Cacheable.
Everything worked fine until I added @Cacheable to the process method in CustomerLookupInvoker class referenced above

```
  @Cacheable("customerLookupServiceRS")
  public CustomerLookupServiceRS process(CustomerLookupServiceRQ
  customerLookupServiceRQ) throws PricingServiceException {
```

This is the error I get is:

```
Caused By: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
        Error creating bean with name 'applicationContext-main' defined in URL
        [file:/C:/builds/prcgsvc/ear/APP-INF/classes/beanRefContext.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; 
        nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate 
        bean class [org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext]: 
            Constructor threw exception; 
        nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
            Error creating bean with name 'HcPricingSystemPivotCommon' defined in class path 
            resource [spring-pricing.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; 
            nested exception is org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException
    : Failed to convert property value of type 'com.sun.proxy.$Proxy80 implementing 
    com.xxx.pricing.sao.Invoker,org.springframework.aop.SpringProxy,org.springframework.aop.framework.Advised' 
    to required type 'com.xxxx.pricing.sao.rsi.CustomerLookupInvoker' for 
    property 'customerLookupInvoker'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
        Cannot convert value of
    type [com.sun.proxy.$Proxy80 implementing 
          com.erac.pricing.sao.Invoker,org.springframework.aop.SpringProxy,org.springframework.aop.framework.Advised] 
                  to required type [com.xxxx.pricing.sao.rsi.CustomerLookupInvoker] for 
                  property 'customerLookup
    Invoker': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java
```

Here is code for HcPricingSystemPivotCommon

```
public class HcPricingSystemPivotCommon {
  private CustomerLookupInvoker customerLookupInvoker;
  private EcarsApplicationPropertyUtil ecarsApplicationPropertyUtil;
  private MessageHandlerUtil messageHandlerUtil;

  /**
   * This method tries to determine the pricing path code. 
   *
   */
  public RatePathCodeEnumeration evaluateRatePathCode(RatePathCodeEnumeration ratePathCode,
    SystemIdEnumeration pricingSystemId, String pickupPeopleSoftId, GregorianCalendar pivotDateTime,
    String customerNumber, String lineOfBusiness)
      throws ValidationException {

    if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(customerNumber)) {
      return evaluateRatePathCodeForCustomer(customerNumber, pickupPeopleSoftId, pivotDateTime);
    }
    return ratePathCode;
  }

  public CustomerLookupInvoker getCustomerLookupInvoker() {
    return customerLookupInvoker;
  }

  public EcarsApplicationPropertyUtil getEcarsApplicationPropertyUtil() {
    return ecarsApplicationPropertyUtil;
  }

  public MessageHandlerUtil getMessageHandlerUtil() {
    return messageHandlerUtil;
  }

  public void setCustomerLookupInvoker(CustomerLookupInvoker customerLookupInvoker) {
    this.customerLookupInvoker = customerLookupInvoker;
  }

  public void setEcarsApplicationPropertyUtil(
    EcarsApplicationPropertyUtil ecarsApplicationPropertyUtil) {
    this.ecarsApplicationPropertyUtil = ecarsApplicationPropertyUtil;
  }

  public void setMessageHandlerUtil(MessageHandlerUtil messageHandlerUtil) {
    this.messageHandlerUtil = messageHandlerUtil;
  }

  /**
   */
  private RatePathCodeEnumeration evaluateRatePathCodeForCustomer(String customerNumber,
    String pickupPeopleSoftId, GregorianCalendar pivotDateTime)
      throws ValidationException {
    RatePathCodeEnumeration ratePathCode = null;

    CustomerLookupServiceRQ customerLookupServiceRQ = new CustomerLookupServiceRQ();

    /* Set Keys */
    customerLookupServiceRQ.setCustomerNumber(customerNumber);

    CustomerLookupServiceRS customerLookupServiceRS = customerLookupInvoker.process(
        customerLookupServiceRQ);
    CustomerInformation customerInformation = customerLookupServiceRS.getCustomerInformation();

    if (null != customerInformation) {
        ratePathCode = RatePathCodeEnumeration.GENESIS;
    }

    return ratePathCode;
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you share code for `com.xxxx.pricing.pivot.HcPricingSystemPivotCommon` ?

Comment: @Amit.rk3  posted code as requested

Comment: You should be programming to interfaces (`RsiInvoker<CustomerLookupServiceRQ, CustomerLookupServiceRS>`) instead of concrete classes (`CustomerLookupInvoker `). When using AOP by default spring is using proxies in your case JDK Dynamic proxies which are interface based. Hence you get a dynamic object which is a `RsiInvoker<CustomerLookupServiceRQ, CustomerLookupServiceRS>` but not a `CustomerLookupInvoker` hence while injecting a classcast occurs. Use the interfaces instead of actual classes. (That is the whole point of using an interface!).

Comment: @M. Deinum  agree with the comment to program to interfaces, but RsiInvoker is an abstract class that implements the Invoker interface.  So I am confused how to do that in this situation.

Comment: Why would it change, I just took the wrong one use `Invoker` instead.